# network shares not working once the server has been restarted

Tags: windows-server-2003

We have a file server running Windows 2003 Server which has several folder shares.
When I have to shut down the file server for maintenance, I have to reboot every single workstation as their shortcuts don't work after the file server is rebooted.

Comment: What are the shortcut configurations?

Comment: What OS on the workstations?

Comment: windows Xp Professional

Comment: I am sure there must be a simple solution that i am over looking but after searching the web i am not sure what it is?

Answer (score 1):

Are the shortcuts pointing to a UNC path or a network drive mapped on the workstation? There seems to be a problem with network drives not refreshing themselves automatically.
If it's an UNC path, I'd see if file server's IP changes after a reboot, maybe its a dns cache issue.